# Author Link in Recent Posts Widget

Tags: widgets, list-authors, recent-posts

I want to add author link into the recent post widget. For example if any user post on my web from his LinkedIn ID (which I have allowed) so in Recent Posts where it shows, `<time>` By: `<author>` so user can go to his/her LinkedIn profile by clicking on his name `<author>`. I know its code will be something like `get_author_link();` but don't know where and how to code it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the rather simplistic approach would be: copy the whole `WP_Widget_Categories` from `wp-includes/default-widgets.php`, and paste it to your `functions.php`.

In there, you could modify the output by customizing this part of the class:

```
class WP_Widget_Recent_Posts extends WP_Widget {

...

    <?php echo $before_widget; ?>
    <?php if ( $title ) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>
    <ul>
    <?php  while ($r->have_posts()) : $r->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title() ? get_the_title() : get_the_ID()); ?>"><?php if ( get_the_title() ) the_title(); else the_ID(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php echo $after_widget; ?>

...

}
```

I think there may be a better way to do this, but that's the only way I know at the moment. :s

Comment: Can you please tell me where to edit (on which line) and what to edit in these coding. Thanks.